# How to synchronously read from stdin when spawning a process in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I use NodeJS 16 and the function [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) to start a process. The callee spits out data after each input per line.

Example:

```
ping <--- stdin by caller
pong <--- stdout by callee
ping <--- stdin by caller
pong <--- stdout by callee
```

I use [subprocess.stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocessstdout) to retrieve the ..well...stdout.

The code `p.stdout.on('data', (data: Buffer) => console.log)` works fine, but `p.stdout.read(16)` to read (and wait for 16 bytes) returns null.

How can I retrieve the data, even if it's blocking ?

Comment: Can you show the part of code where the error occurs

Comment: p.stdout.read fails with null, whereas p.stdout.on works fine.